# Can we enable other LaTeX formatting commands? Not just math?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, formatting

How can I enable other LaTeX functions to write formatted answers here in Math.SE?

Tried, for example, to use an array

\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{x[0]$\to $} & 1.000000000 \
 \text{x[1]$\to $} & 0.6839397206 \
 \text{x[2]$\to $} & 0.5774544772 \
 \text{x[3]$\to $} & 0.5672297377 \
 \text{x[4]$\to $} & 0.5671432965 \
 \text{x[5]$\to $} & 0.5671432904
\end{array}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
\end{enumerate}

But it didn't work very well. Enumerate too. I think it is useful to write math too. Is there a way to enable the array and enumerate commands or is it always  necessary to make figures?

If figures are always needed, how can I ask to change it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no TeX implementation at work which could be interpreting the LaTeX code, it is just some JavaScript library (MathJax) who interprets a syntax which looks like LaTeX's **math mode** (and which only interprets the bits between `$`). It also doesn't support everything which LaTeX supports there (for example, no definitions of new commands, no conditionals, etc.)

So, no writing of whole articles in LaTeX here.

For text formatting (like enumerations), just use the [Markdown syntax](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help):

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
```

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

Comment: Actually, `\newcommand` and `\DeclareMathOperator` work, `$\newcommand{\Ext}[3]{{\rm Ext}^#1(#2,#3)}$ $\Ext{1}{A}{B}$` gives $\newcommand{\Ext}[3]{{\rm Ext}^#1(#2,#3)}$ $\Ext{1}{A}{B}$ (not that I recommend using such a construction but I couldn't think of anything better at the moment)

Comment: Is this missing a `\\`? Interesting, though.

Comment: I just tried and the backslash doesn't seem to matter, but you're right it's better now...

Comment: Testing...$\newcommand{\Ext}[3]{{\rm Ext}^#1(#2,#3)}$ $\Ext{1}{A}{B}$...very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @t.b., that's interesting. It doesn't treat each math mode block as separate entities? For some reason, I thought it would and have not tried to create a command early on and reuse it. That serves me right, for not testing it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If the $\LaTeX$ command you want isn't in [this list](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/tex.html#supported-latex-commands), you can't use it. See [this FAQ item](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#unrecognized-TeX) as well.